# Slim PHP not seeing url params Windows Server with IIS

Tags: php, iis, slim

I have slim framework set up on a windows server 2012 box using IIS 6.2 and have Slim php framework *almost* working. Slim correctly handles urls without params like this:

```
$app->get('/books', function () {
        echo "Yay book!";
});
```

but once we add in url parameters (See: http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/params/ ) like this:

```
$app->get('/books/:one/:two', function ($one, $two) {
        echo "The first parameter is " . $one;
        echo "The second parameter is " . $two;
});
```

it fails with a 404. I have been digging into my web.config file and after dissecting it, it still looks correct to me, here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="slim" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

One further note, the slim api is located in a subdirectory of web root, /api, and that is where this web.config lives.

Comment: How are you calling the route?

Comment: I was doing `www.example.com/api/books/a/b` In any case, I've figured out my issue. It was the version of slim, as detailed in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently SLIM changed how their requests work from Version 2 to Version 3. The correct way to write that `/books` endpoint is like so:

```
$app->get('/books/{one}/{two}', function ($request, $response) {
        echo "The first parameter is " . $request->getAttribute('one');
        echo "The second parameter is " . $request->getAttribute('two');
});
```

I had a co-worker install this so wasnt aware he had installed the newer version.